# Propagate Bash function return code as script exit error code

Tags: bash

In my Bash script `foo.sh` I have a function `bar()` that may encounter an error:

```bash
bar() {
  # if some error condition
    return 1;
}

bar
```

I want to propagate the result of the function to the caller of `foo.sh` (i.e. as the exit code of the script). I know that `return 1` will cause `$?` to be populated with this return code. But how do I propagate that to the script's caller? Does it happen automatically? Or do I need to do this?

```bash
bar() {
  # if some error condition
    return 1;
}

bar
exit $?
```

Or should I just exit inside the function? (That seems like bad practice on the face of it.)

```bash
bar() {
  # if some error condition
    exit 1;
}

bar
```

Comment: One common convention is a `die()` function which prints an appropriate message and exits with the right value

Comment: `$?` is the default exit status already. `exit "$?"` is completely redundant; `bar || exit` suffices when bar _isn't_ the last line of the script; when it is, `bar` alone meets your needs.

Comment: To be very clear, using `return` inside `bar` and then invoking as `bar || exit` is what I (strongly) suggest; it avoids running afoul of [BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises).

Comment: Your script already does what you want it to do. See: `bash foo.sh; echo $?`

Comment: The caller of the function could retrieve `$?` and then do an exit. For instance y doing `bar || exit $?`. This has the effect that, if you change your function from `return 1` to i.e. `return 42`,  the 42 would be sent to the script's caller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few relevant principles:

- The last line of a script has its exit status propagated to the caller.

  Thus, `bar` alone is sufficient to propagate an exit status back to the parent process, if you're certain that no other code will be added in the future that runs later.
- When `exit` or `return` is invoked with no arguments, `$?` is the default value.

  Thus, `bar || exit` is explicit "if bar fails, exit *immediately*, passing its exit status to the caller".
- `set -e` [is a bad idea](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises), and so are moral equivalents like (incautious) ERR traps.

Comment: This answer is direct, concise, to the point, and very helpful. Thank you! I don't want to get too far off topic, but I had been using `set -e` at the top of the script to catch errors when invoking external commands such as `uploadSomeFile`; in this case it wouldn't make sense to continue if the command failed. I infer from your answer that the correct approach, instead of using `set -e`, would be to use `uploadSomeFile || exit` in every such case?

Comment: Correct; explicit `|| exit` (or, when in a function and otherwise appropriate, `|| return`) doesn't have the pitfalls, traps and caveats covered in the linked FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

```
trap 'exit 1' ERR
```

You could replace `exit 1` wit your own error handling implementation for sure.

Must read page: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Comment: This is just `set -e` but squashing other exit values to 1 (so making `return 2` act like `return 1` when it's not flagged as "checked", suppressing both `set -e` and the ERR trap); I can't see the value.

Comment: Depend on how you implement the code inside trap.

Comment: Well, yes, but you're providing an implementation here. :)

Comment: I'm not supposed to do OP work, I gave some hints